# Replace Links Location (href='...')

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, html-parsing

I would like to replace the link location (of anchor tag) of a page as follows.

Sample Input:

```
text text text <a href='http://test1.com/'> click </a> text text
other text <a class='links' href="gallery.html" title='Look at the gallery'> Gallery</a>
more text
```

Sample Output

```
text text text <a href='http://example.com/p.php?q=http://test1.com/'> click </a> text text
other text <a class='links' href="http://example.com/p.php?q=gallery.html" title='Look at the gallery'> Gallery</a>
more text
```

I hope I have make it clear. Anyway I am trying to do it with PHP and reg-ex. Would you please light me up with right.

Thank you
Sadi

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: @icktoofay Unless you are Jay-Z with 99 problems :P

Comment: If you have better solution then reg-ex, please share. I need to solve the problem efficiently. Any sort of effective solutions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for parsing HTML.

Do use PHP's built-in XML parsing engine. It works quite well on your question (and answers the question to boot):

```
<?php
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // ignore malformed HTML
  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->loadHTMLFile("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099187/replace-links-location-href"); 
  foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
   $link->setAttribute('href', "http://www.google.com/?q=" . $link->getAttribute('href'));
  }
  echo $xml->saveHTML();  // output to browser, save to file, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me test it. But one morething the HTML could be malformed :( So, I might be need to use it as libxml_use_internal_errors(false); isn't it?

Comment: The libxml engine will actually fix invalidly nested tags. `libxml_use_internal_errors(false)` simply prevents the PHP script from polluting page output with warnings about bad HTML.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use str_replace ();

```
   $string = 'your text';
   $newstring = str_replace ('href="', 'href="http://example.com/p.php?q=', $string);
```